# Admob Conversion Tracking in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I tried to set conversion tracking in my iOS game, but I didn't be able to do that. The tutorial can be found here: https://developers.google.com/app-conversion-tracking/ios/?hl=it#usage_and_disclosure

I integrate the GoogleConversionTrackingSDK to my project, load AdSupport framework and type -ObjC in Other linker flags.
I tried to convert this snippet from Obj-C:

```objc
[ACTConversionReporter reportWithConversionID:@"MY_ID" label:@"MY_LABEL" value:@"MY_VALUE" isRepeatable:NO];
```

to Swift:

```swift
ACTConversionReporter.reportWithConversionID("MY_ID", label: "MY_LABEL", value: "MY_VALUE", isRepeatable: false)
```

and I put that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method of AppDelegate.swift, but I get the error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'ACTConversionReporter'

If I type in Obj-C bridging header in Swift Compiler - Code Generation in Build Settings "ACTReporter.h" (without qm), I put the header file in the folder of my game or if I type the whole path of "ACTReporter.h" ending with its name, I fail the build and I get 2 errors:

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ACTConversionReporter", referenced from:
>         type metadata accessor for __ObjC.ACTConversionReporter in AppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I don't know what to do. I hope there is someone who can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to your project "YourProjectName-Bridging-Header.h" file

[Here you can see how to add the file](http://www.learnswiftonline.com/getting-started/adding-swift-bridging-header/)

in Bridging Header file add `#import "ACTReporter.h"`

Then it will work for you!